# 2-col CSS layout with background colors that fill full height?

Tags: css

I've had a reasonable amount of exposure to CSS layout.

I've looked at quite a few CSS layouts for 2 or 3 column layouts, and having a hard time to just find even just a reliable 2 column that allows me to do the following:

what I want:

- each column has its own background color
- i want the background column to fill the full height of the page
- i dont know which column will contain most text so each column must resize independently

of all the layouts i've found - or attempted myself they all have one of these problems

- an image is needed for the background (somewhat clever but yuk!)
- the background color only fills the full height if that column is the longest

I'm very tempted to just revert back to `<TABLE>` which I can reliably implement in about 3 lines of code.

Comment: Good choice... background image is the way to go.  Tables are for **tabular data**.  :)  Good luck!

Comment: You commented that you are currently using the image solution that was posted. Why not mark it as the answer... looks like some people actually took a decent amount of time to provide you with quality help.

Answer (score 3):

If [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) isn't your thing try **[multi-column layouts](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/)**.

Remove content from either block (there's plenty of it) to try it out.

This was always a thing I had trouble with - I'd advise you to bookmark **[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/)** and have a look through some of the articles in the CSS category. They have some excellent tutorials and writeups there for frontend coders (things like CSS sprites, liquid layouts, fonts etc.).

Comment: I'd forgotten about/never used the multi-column layouts. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem with the image-background, what on earth would justify using tables? It seems very backwards to me. The image-background gives you proper markup, the desired effect, and has cross-browser compatibility.

You could use Javascript - but that is really not necessary.

Comment: that i wouldnt have to create a new image everytime I wanted to change the width or color of the bars. i was kind of playing devils advocate by suggesting tables but i know for sure it'll work and i'm not completely sure i care.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a fixed height (probably not a viable solution) or use the faux-column technique by using a background image (which you've already labeled as a *problem*), you're pretty much out of luck.

The faux-column technique is widely used and is functional cross-browser. Why is that not a viable solution for you?

Comment: 'faux column' just doesnt seem that elegant. i'm jsut surprised that thats the 'best' solution CSS seems to be able to provide

Comment: one reason i was against the faux column idea is I want to be able to dynamically change the width without having to create a new image. ultimately i may create a .NET control to help with column layouts and i'd rather it not have to use precreated images.

Answer (score 1):

If I have your question correct, your layout should be as simple as:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col1">Blahblah</div>
    <div class="col2">Blahblah</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

styles.css:

```
 .wrapper { background-image: url(imageTile.gif); background-repeat: repeat-y; }
 .col1 { float: left; width: 100px; margin-right: 20px; }
 .col2 { float: left; width: 100px; }
 .clear { clear: both; }
```

Forget a table, IMO this is much easier.  Heights will flex with content.  The imageTile.gif should be a 1px by [x]px slice of the background color, where [x] is the width of the page.

Comment: If you couple this answer with some javascript, you can achieve the balance columns. The logic is quite simple

IF A > B
  C = B
ELSE
  C = A

Alternatively you can look at Logan's answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448164/2-col-css-layout-with-background-colors-that-fill-full-height#448304

Answer (score 1):

This is not a hard problem to solve, so I don't advise you go back to tables. I am a bit confused on what exactly you want though, so let me try to help you in the best way that I can.

```
<div class="a">Text A</div>
<div class="b">Text B</div>
```

With CSS:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.a
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; /* For IE */
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}

.b
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

That will give you something like this: [for-simon.html](http://loganfs.com/testing/for-simon.html)

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I spent (wasted) a lot of time looking for a nice CSS solution to this. Dude, use a table. We won't tell anyone.

Comment: As much as I love css and use it religiously, +1 for overcoming ideology and getting things done before you pull all your hair out.

Comment: currenlty i'm using a background image. it took about 1 minute to implement. it seems to work quite nicely but i hate it!

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never. Thought this might help:

The htmls

```
<div id="content"> 
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

The csss

```
#content { background-color: #F1EBD9; }
#left { float: left; width: 14em; }
#right { margin-left: 14em; background-color: #FFF; }
```

You can view this @ http://alexandergutierrez.info/stretch-background-color-in-a-two-col-layout