# Fixed width(lefthand) menu with Iframe filling remainder

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to create a relatively simple page with a  that is on the left side, taking up the whole height of the browsers window, with a fixed width (say 200px), and then an  that uses the rest of the window width, and also the whole windows height. I want to use CSS to do it, no javascript. I don't mind wrapping the  in a  if I have to.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289409/full-height-css-layout-with-multiple-columns or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448164/2-col-css-layout-with-background-colors-that-fill-full-height or various other articles on this site. Do some searching, you should find what you need.

Comment: I may be missing something, but according to my knowledge, that doesn't help when using an iframe.  Divs, sure, but an iframe?  Doesn't work, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="min-width: 200px;" bgcolor="#333333">

            </td>
            <td width="100%" bgcolor="#666666">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Now what I should say is that I have only tested this in Firefox and Safari (mac user) so I don't know how it will look in Internet Explorer etc, but feel free to try it, this should give you what you want :)